# What does the % operator do for strings in InstallScript?

Tags: installscript

I'm looking at some InstallScript code.

With integers, I'm used to the % operator being modulo.  I'm not familiar with it in strings.

```
if (szSomeString % szSomeOtherString) then
   // do something
endif;
```

What is this shorthand for?

I realize this should be braindead simple to Google for but I haven't found any luck yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [InstallScript Reference Guide](http://kb.flexerasoftware.com/doc/DocumentRepository/Installation/InstallShield/InstallShield%202012%20Professional/01_Public/Product_Manual/InstallShield2012InstallScriptReferenceGuide.pdf):

```
Find String Operator (%) Locates a substring in another string
```